# Granted all privileges on my PostGres table, but still am getting a "Permission denied" error when attempting to insert/select

Tags: postgresql, select, permissions, insert, sql-grant

I'm using PostGres 9.5.  I'm having trouble inserting data into a table I just created.  I'm getting "permission denied" errors despite granting all privileges to the database user.  See below ...

```
localhost:myapp davea$ psql -Upostgres
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.5.0, server 9.5.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# GRANT ALL ON schema public TO myapp;
GRANT

localhost:myapp davea$ psql -Upostgres
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.5.0, server 9.5.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# GRANT USAGE ON schema public TO myapp;
GRANT
postgres=# \q
localhost:myapp davea$ myapp
psql (9.5.0, server 9.5.1)
Type "help" for help.

myapp=> insert into search_codes (id, code, address_id) values (1, 'atlanta', 'GA');
ERROR:  permission denied for relation search_codes
myapp=> select * FROM search_codes;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation search_codes
myapp=> \d search_codes;
                                Table "public.search_codes"
   Column   |       Type        |                         Modifiers
------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer           | not null default nextval('search_codes_id_seq'::regclass)
 code       | character varying |
 address_id | character varying |
Indexes:
    "search_codes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_search_codes_on_code" UNIQUE, btree (code)
    "index_search_codes_on_address_id" btree (address_id)
```

What's the proper way to grant privileges so that my user can insert and select from the table?

Comment: Do you have a separate database or are all your tables in the postgres default database?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your first command give you the ability to list table (you can just know that there are existing)

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO myapp
```

Then you have to grant SELECT, INSERT, etc... to all the tables in the schema public

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myapp
```

I recommand not giving all privileges to a specific app.

If you have sequences :

```
 GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to myapp
```

If you have functions :

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO myapp
```

Then your example will work.

But you still have to apply some command if you want futur created table to be able to be accessed :

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLES TO myapp
```

Postgresql have a very weird mecanism it took me a while to understand it !

Comment: Any other suggestions if you've done this and it still doesn't work?

Comment: I think you should ask a new question then

Comment: I tried everything but it didn't work. I had to change the ownership of tables and schema. `ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable OWNER TO username;`, `ALTER SCHEMA myschema OWNER TO username;`

Answer (score 6):

At first you have to login your new database using postgres user

```
psql your_db_name -U postgres -h your_host_name
```

give the ability to list table

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO your_user_name
```

Then you have to grant permission to all the tables in the schema public

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO your_user_name
```

If you have sequences then give permission

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO your_user_name
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error on "ALL" in all above queries with ALL in greenplum.

       ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALL"
    LINE 1: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO neera...
                                ^
    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: syntax error at or near "ALL"
    SQL state: 42601
    Character: 25

Comment: what database actually u are using mysql or postgres??Cause your command seems work for me in postgres or may be you are doing something wrong in your previous command

Comment: I am using greenplum

Answer (score 2):

You're granting permissions in the postgres database instead of the myapp database.

Change the first PSQL command to

```
psql -Upostgres myapp
```

And then issue the grants

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33943/granting-access-to-all-tables-for-a-user.

I think  your issue is that GRANTs are different for the database, schemas, and tables so you need to set permissions on the tables explicitly.

Comment: Not understanding you.  What statements do I ened to run and as what user?